# keyboard layout settings in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I've been using a costumed keyboard layout in previous ubuntu changing the files `keypad` and `kpdl` in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`.

I modified the legacy layout, so I used to choose `legacy` in `numeric keypad layout selection` in `system settings`, but now in Ubuntu 13.10 I cannot find the similar path.

How do change the numeric keypad layout in Ubuntu 13.10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the similar options are available in Ubuntu 13.10 installing the `Tweak Tool - Tweak advanced GNOME 3` settings from the Ubuntu Software Center.